# A function which is not linear with respect to a given variable/variables

Tags: functions

I've just started to learn Artificial Intelligence and I have found that neural networks uses an activation function to make their output non-linear.

What does mean that a function is non linear or linear?

Comment: A linear function is a first-degree (polynomial) function.

Answer (score 0):

Linearity of a function $f$ is defined as
$$
f(\lambda x + \mu y) = \lambda f(x) + \mu f(y),
$$
for all numbers $\lambda,\mu$ (in the relevant field) and allowed inputs $x,y$ for $f$. Thus, twice the input gives twice the output for $f$. Another example usefull for understanding is $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. [See Wikipedia for more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function).

Examples of nonlinear functions of $x$ are $ax+b,x^2,\sin(x)$.